# Job portal using Joomla 1.5.15

Tags: joomla1.5

I want to build a Job portal using joomla 1.5. So anyone have some contents or guides from where i can start this site. And anyone can tell how to start it as i m a begineer in joomla.

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways you can accomplish that.

1. Code the job portal component yourself. Some good MVC coding will do the trick. If youre a beginner this can be difficult.
2. Use a free or commercial component form extensions.joomla.org which suits your needs best.
   Joomlart has done a Job board component you should check: 
   http://www.joomlart.com/addons/components_and_modules/ja_job_board.html
3. Use one of the CCK components out there to build your job board (ZOO, Flexicontent, K2)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jobberbase.com/